# How to get the border width of a widget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, border, stylesheet

I have a QTableView that overrides sizeHint() and returns a QSize by adding up the heights/widths of all columns/rows + the height/width of the headers.

However the result is still slightly too small and shows scrollbars unless I either...

1. Set the stylesheet to `border-width: 0;`
2. Add 2px to the sizeHint

I want borders, so that leaves me with #2. But I now need to be able to have the user change the style which may change the border size, so rather than just adding `2px` I need to get the `border-width*2`. How can I do that?

The following code returns prints `3` which is incorrect, but it's the only reference to borders I could find in the QStyle docs

```
style = self.style()
print(style.pixelMetric(style.PM_MenuPanelWidth))
```

Comment: There may be a small margin (usually 1or 2 pixels) that can be calculated with `table.width() - table.viewport().width()`. There's also `table.frameWidth()`, but I don't know how that interacts with stylesheets - and in any case, a [widget's size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) does not include its frame.

Comment: 2*frameWidth() worked, thanks! It still ends up the wrong size when using the qdarkstyle theme, but pretty sure that's unrelated to the border width and this works for the builtin themes.

Comment: Did you check the margin? I'm pretty sure that the margin and frame-width will have similar values (but it may well depend on the style).